# What happens if i set all Windows Services to Manual? Is it safe?

Tags: windows-10, services

I know it sounds like a dumb idea, but I'm curious. What would happen if i set all the Windows services to manual? Is my computer still functional that way? Will it not make a huge difference? Or will i break something?

I'm asking this so i can get rid of all unnecessary startup processes.

If it's not safe to do so, then what are the most important services that i cannot change to manual?

Comment: _I'm asking this so i can get rid of all unnecessary startup processes._ - That's fine, but why do you want to disable all windows services?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't simply switch all services to manual or disable them. They all have some task to do, and you could only disable services you know you won't absolutely need.

[Which Windows 10 Services can you safely disable?](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/which-windows-10-services-safe-to-disable) from TheWindowsClub seems quite reasonable and has a list of services with conditions for disabling them safely.

Comment: +1 for great source.

Comment: Why shouldn't I set all services to manual? Wouldn't they start when needed?